# Dynamic database search result on a website

Tags: search, dynamic, web, content-management-system

This question regards website programming. My primary languages are c++/c# and I don't know much about web development, except that say I understand html and css. That's why I'm looking for a relatively simple solution, preferably something out of the box. I don't have any experience with JavaScript, but for the sake of this project I'm willing to learn it if necessary.

Let's say I have a database, where each entry is about a book. It contains the fields: title, author(s) and publication date.

I would like to create a simple website with a search box that has this dynamic result feature, so that you get suggestions after you type in a few letters. All those suggestions, as well as search results, need to be based purely on the database.

This could be a static website or based on any Content Management System, I'm familiar with Joomla, but was unable to find an out-of-the box component that would do just that. All those search modules search the entire website and I only need to search the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I can help you with how to implement this feature. We used to call this feature as autocomplete menu.

First you decide minimum characters to populate autocomplete menu. For example 2

By using javascript you write keyup event. Once the characters count reaches to the minimum character count. You send AJAX request to the server.

The server should process this request and do the database search and form a json or xml response or plain text to the client.

The client parses that response into javascript object and construct a dynamic html for autocomplete menu with the data and render it into the DOM hence display's just below the search text box.

Now if you want to display the first result inside the textbox as you type. Here is the method I can suggest as similar as google search box

Place one label or span just below the input text box. By using css make its position exactly match with the position of the text box. Make sure the starting of text of both input text and label matches. Make the text color of the label less brighter than the font color of text. The font size and font family of the label should match the input text field's style. Now by using Javascript display the first or most matched text inside the label. Please find the sample code below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
       <style>
         label {
           position:relative;
         }
         body, input {
      font-family: 'verdana';
      font-size: 12px;
         }

      </style>
    </head>
    <html>
    <body>

      <form action="demo_form.asp">
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Matched Text" /><br>
        <label> Matched Text</label><br>
     </form>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This sounds plausible even for a beginner. I understand the search results will be placed under the search box. How about if we wanted to see suggestions within the search box as we type?

Comment: @marcin-kmiec, I have modified my answer. Does it answer your question now?

Comment: That's a nice trick. Thank you! I wonder how google handles this.